# Как получить статус сообщения через telegram-api?

Tags: telegram, telethon, pyrogram

Мне нужно программно получить статус сообщения (доставлено прочитано) через MTProto. Я использую python telethon / pyrogram

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: вы про Bot API  или про MTProto? если про первое, то (насколько я помню) - никак